# Using preg_replace to change <title> tag in php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

So I will provide this code for example:

```
$str='<title>Test title here</title><meta name="description" content="test meta content here">';
$jftitle="here title 1";
$jfmeta ="here meta 2";
```

And I have:

```
$str=preg_replace(array('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i','/<meta name="description" content="(.*)">/i'),array('<title>'.$jftitle.'</title>','<meta name="description" content="'.$jfmeta.'">'),$str);
```

If I do an echo on the $str, it returns " ".
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `echo htmlspecialchars($str);`